# Knuth Dancing Links with Secondary Columns

Tags: algorithm, doubly-linked-list, knuth

I have implemented [Knuth's "Dancing Links" algorithm](https://github.com/seanlaw/avm/blob/master/dlx.py) to explore the generalized exact cover problem (i.e., with secondary columns). The code works as expected for an exact cover (i.e., all columns are primary columns) and so for a simple sparse matrix:

```
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

My code returns the following set of rows as solutions:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 4]
[5]
```

And I have also tested this with many other exact cover examples and it checks out. However, the details regarding the secondary columns is a bit vague. From what I could gather from various [Knuth](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~jchu/publicportal/sudoku/0011047.pdf)/[non-Knuth](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1b9d/a79d3d3b54b3d9e4d8c4be040e132e1c8fd1.pdf) resources, it says that what you need to do is:

> The only difference is that we initialize the data structure by making
>   a circular list of the column headers for the primary columns only. The header for each
>   secondary column should have L and R fields that simply point to itself. The remainder
>   of the algorithm proceeds exactly as before, so we will still call it algorithm DLX.

After making these changes to how the matrix/nodes/headers is represented and then setting the first column as a secondary column (i.e., only columns 2 and 3 are primary), I end up with the following sets of rows as solutions:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 3]
[4]
[5]
```

While all of these are valid solutions and some overlap with exact the exact cover solutions, it appears that other solutions are missing (i.e., some of those from the exact cover solution set):

```
[0, 1, 2]
[2, 4]
```

Perhaps this is a misunderstanding on my part but am I missing something conceptually or is Knuth’s explanation incomplete?

**It would even be helpful if you could show that your algorithm produces the full set of solutions and this will help me confirm that my algorithm is incomplete!**

Unfortunately, even [Knuth's "Art of Computer Programming"](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc5c.ps.gz) regarding dancing links doesn't seem to offer too much help.

Comment: Apart from Knuths' [2000 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0011047) and [Fascicle 5c (draft .ps.gz)](http://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc5c.ps.gz), you can also look at his actual implementations (in CWEB) from his [website](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs.html) — see the programs [DANCE](https://github.com/shreevatsa/knuth-literate-programs/blob/master/programs/dance.pdf) and [DLX1](https://github.com/shreevatsa/knuth-literate-programs/blob/master/programs/dlx1.pdf).

Comment: BTW what you've implemented is what Knuth calls (in fasc5c page 3, i.e. 7.2.2.1 equation (9)) the natural recursive algorithm that leads to (what Knuth in that section calls) Algorithm X. The term “dancing links” as used by Knuth refers to a particular low-level implementation detail involving pointers and linked lists, that make it really efficient on a computer (if coding in a language like C).

Comment: I've already looked at those resources and referenced them in my original post. Perhaps I've missed your point but how does this information help me with the implementation of the generalized cover problem where secondary columns are involved? That's the problem that I'm trying to solve. I'm not a computer scientist and so the programs provided by Knuth are very challenging for me to follow.

Comment: Well you didn't mention having looked at the C programs in your question, so I mentioned it in my first comment, in case it helps you. Also, you quoted from the 2000 paper but I find the exposition in the draft fasc5c simpler. And it was a comment not an answer precisely because if it answered your question I'd have posted it as an answer :-) Anyway, I've looked into this now; I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I would greatly appreciate it if you are able help me solve this problem. I look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Definition

This is how the exact cover problem is extended to non-primary items on page 7 (currently) of [Pre-Fascicle 5C](http://cs.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fasc5c.ps.gz), Dancing Links:

> ...an exact cover problem involves N distinct items, of which N1 are primary and N2 = N - N1 are secondary. It is defined by a family of options, each of which is a subset of the items. *Every option must include at least one primary item.* The task is to find all subsets of the options that (i) contain every primary item exactly one, and (ii) contain every secondary item at most once.
>
> (Options that are purely secondary are excluded from this new definition, because they will never be chosen by Algorithm X as we've refined it. If for some reason you don't like that rule, you can always go back to the idea of slack options. Exercise 19 discusses another interesting alternative.)

Your question is answered by the emphasized (by Knuth) sentence in the first paragraph, and by the second paragraph. The exact cover problem being solved by Knuth disallows (or ignores) options that don't help cover the primary items, i.e. are made up purely of secondary items.

### Example

In your example in the question, let's call the columns A, B, C, where A is secondary, and B and C are primary. The options are:

```
[0, 1, 0] -- option 0: [B]
[0, 0, 1] -- option 1: [C]
[1, 0, 0] -- option 2: [A]
[1, 1, 0] -- option 3: [A, B]
[0, 1, 1] -- option 4: [B, C]
[1, 1, 1] -- option 5: [A, B, C]
```

So here the third row `[1 0 0]`, i.e. option 2, contains no primary items.

You can run either of Knuth's programs DANCE or DLX1 with the following input in a file called (say) `foo.dlx`:

```
B C | A
B
C
A
A B
B C
A B C
```

The programs find the same four solutions:

```
$ ./dance 1 < foo.dlx
1:
 C (1 of 3)
 B (1 of 2)
2:
 C (1 of 3)
 B A (2 of 2)
3:
 C B (2 of 3)
4:
 C A B (3 of 3)
Altogether 4 solutions, after 12 updates.
```

or

```
% ./dlx1 m1 < foo.dlx
Option ignored (no primary items): A
(5 options, 2+1 items, 14 entries successfully read)
1:
 C (1 of 3)
 B (1 of 2)
2:
 C (1 of 3)
 B A (2 of 2)
3:
 C B (2 of 3)
4:
 C A B (3 of 3)
Altogether 4 solutions, 261+231 mems, 12 updates, 360 bytes, 6 nodes.
```

(Note the explicit warning in the second program, that Option 2, which contains only the secondary item A, is ignored.)

### Solution 1: Change the problem

If you remove options (rows) that contain no primary items (columns), then  the program already works: the solutions you get are indeed exhaustive for the new problem.

### Solution 2: Slack options

As Knuth says in the second quoted paragraph (ignore the Exercise 19 alternative; it's for solving a different problem), if you really want to include options that contain only secondary items, you can go back to the idea of slack options. In the 2000 paper, this idea is the very next sentence after the paragraph you quoted:

> A generalized cover problem can be converted to an equivalent exact cover problem if we simply append one row for each secondary column, containing a single 1 in that column.

(That is, for every secondary item, we add an option that contains only that item, and now treat it as an exact cover problem with only primary items.)

In more detail, I assume you want to solve the following problem:

- There are N distinct items (columns), some of which are primary and others are secondary.
- There is some family of options (rows), each if which is a set of items (columns). **Some of these may contain no primary items.**
- Find all subsets of the options that contain every primary item exactly once, and every secondary item at most once.

To solve this problem, we can do the following:

- Among the given options (rows), identify those that contain only secondary items (columns). So you take the set of all rows that were given, and you partition it into two sets: one set (call it X) in which every option contains at least one primary item, and one set (call it Y) in which every option contains only secondary items.
- For every secondary item, form the option (row) that contains only that item. Let Z be the set of all such one-item (slack) options.
- Now, replace your list of options (X + Y) with (X + Y + Z), where the + is union: there may be some overlap between Y and Z, but you'll keep only one of each option.
- Finally, solve the original exact cover problem (the one in which all options are primary). You'll get a few solutions.
- For each solution you get,

  - first throw away (ignore) every option that wasn't in X or Y (i.e., is one of the slack options you additionally added)
  - of the remaining options, form the set Y' of options in the solution that contain only secondary items. Let X' be the remaining set (i.e. the options in the solution that contain at least one primary item).
  - Append the solution (X' union S) for every subset of Y'.

In your example in the question: X is the following set:

```
[0, 1, 0] -- option 0: [B]
[0, 0, 1] -- option 1: [C]
[1, 1, 0] -- option 3: [A, B]
[0, 1, 1] -- option 4: [B, C]
[1, 1, 1] -- option 5: [A, B, C]
```

and Y is the following set:

```
[1, 0, 0] -- option 2: [A]
```

and Z is same as Y, so you don't need to add anything in this case.

You solve the original exact cover problem (everything is primary), and get the following solutions:

- [0, 1, 2]. Here X' = [0, 1], and Y' = [2] and has two subsets: the empty set ([]), and Y itself ([2]). So add the two solutions [0, 1] and [0, 1, 2].
- [1, 3]. Here X' = [1, 3] and Y' = []. Add the solution [1, 3].
- [2, 4]. Here X' = [4], and Y' = [2]. Add the two solutions [4] and [2, 4].
- [5]. Here X' = [5], and Y' = []. Add the solution [5].

This gives all six solutions.